# Objects extends and object new in PHP

Tags: php

I have create a HTML element constructor

```
class ElementConstructor{
protected $properties=array();
function __construct($properties = array(),$tag=''){
        if($tag!=''){
            $this->element = $tag;
        }
        if(sizeof($this->properties)>0){
            $this->properties = array_merge($this->properties,$properties);
        }else{
            $this->properties = $properties;
        }
    }
function init(){        
        $this->setAttr();
    }
    function setAttr($attr = NULL){
        foreach($this->properties as $name=>$value){
            if($name != 'display')
                $this->doc[$this->element]->attr($name,$value);
        }
    }
}
```

and use is to create some basic class include Div

```
class BasicDiv extends ElementConstructor{
    protected $element = 'div';
}
```

after that, I need to use it

```
class BasicWrapper extends BasicDiv{
        //one (1)
    protected $properties = array(
        'class'=>'row-fluid sortable ui-sortable',
        'id'=>'wrapper'
    );
        ....
        function __construct($config=array(),$properties = array()){
        parent::__construct($properties);
            //(2), the properties replaced by (1)
        $secondLevelWrapper = new BasicDiv(array('id'=>'second_level','class'=>'box span12'));
        $secondLevelWrapper->init();
    }
}
```

However, the output shows there is two DIVs display, which I expected would be (1): id:wrapper, class:row-fluid sortable ui-sortable and (2) id:second_level,class:box span12, but two (1) instead. When I remove id:wrapper, the id of the second one becomes correct. So clearly, the $properties in (1) replaces the $properties in (2). But I have already used new to create a new BasicDiv object, isn't that (1) and (2) are independent to each others?

Comment: Do not create a HTML element constructors. Use **templates** instead

Comment: Just because you can do something does not mean you should; just let your HTML be HTML, for goodness sake.